# Problemas com a ordenação de uma lista de array

Tags: javascript

Estou com seguinte problema:

Tento ordenar uma lista de pessoas contendo o flag que identifica a pessoa (aluno ou Professor), o código da pessoa, o nome da pessoa, o status da pessoa (ativo, inativo, bloqueado) e o status da participação naquela sala (ativo, inativo e bloqueado), todas estas informações dentro de um vetor que chamo de `arrayVelhoAux`. Nisto quero ordenar este vetor de forma alfabética (A,B,C,D,E, ...).

```
arrayVelhoAux.FLG_IDENT_PESSO = arrayCursor[j].FLG_IDENT_PESSO;
arrayVelhoAux.COD_IDENT_PESSO = pessoa.COD_IDENT_PESSO;
arrayVelhoAux.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO = pessoa.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO;
arrayVelhoAux.FLG_STATU_PESSO = pessoa.FLG_STATU_PESSO;
arrayVelhoAux.FLG_STATU_PARTC = arrayCursor[j].FLG_STATU_PARTC;

arrayVelho.push(arrayVelhoAux);
```

Para preenchimento deste vetor estou fazendo um loop, pois existem dados que pego em outras tabelas.Apos o preenchimento total deste vetor eu faço um `.sort()` com intuito de ordena-lo.

```
arrayVelho.sort(compareArray);
```

Na função `compareArray` simplesmente comparo qual é maior. Colocando todas as letras em maiúscula para que todas sejam comparadas no mesmo tamanho.

```
function compareArray(a1,b1) {
    if(a1.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO.toUpperCase() > b1.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO.toUpperCase()) return 1;
    if(a1.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO.toUpperCase() < b1.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO.toUpperCase()) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Aparentemente não existe nada de errado, e algo interessante acontece pois, so está comparando alguns, outros ficam fora de ordem. Como na imagem a seguir.

[image: Problema com ordenação de uma lista de array]

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma solução melhor do que está, ou se teria como concertar e deixar esta solução 100% funcional.

Comment: Seria interessante você criar um exemplo completo, mínimo e verificável que exibe o problema, incluindo a entrada completa.

Comment: Aonde posso criar este exemplo ?

Comment: Edite a pergunta. O que eu quero dizer é que você precisa exibir um código que gere o vetor de entrada da função, para que possamos ver exatamente o que está acontecendo. O problema pode ser nos dados de entrada, por exemplo.

Comment: Não, na verdade cheguei a qse resolver aqui, o problema é que função deve retorna 1, -1 e 0, no meu eu retornada apenas se a é maior que b.

Comment: O problema agora é que a ordenação ficou do menor para o maior.

Comment: Provavelmente mudar a ordem do `if` deve resolver.

Comment: É não funcionou, atualizei a pergunta com a nova função compare

Comment: Verifica ai agora

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renan, é interresante que você retorne um inteiro ao invés de um boolean.

```js
var nomes = ["Alessandro", "Alessandra", "Alexandre", "Aline", "Antônio", "Breno", "Bruna", "Carlos", "Carla", "Célia", "Cecília", "César", "Danilo", "Dalila", "Deneval", "Eduardo", "Eduarda", "Esther", "Elísio", "Fábio", "Fabrício", "Fabrícia", "Félix", "Felícia", "Feliciano", "Frederico", "Fabiano", "Gustavo", "Guilherme", "Gúbio", "Heitor", "Hélio", "Hugo", "Isabel", "Isabela", "Ígor", "João", "Joana", "Júlio César", "Júlio", "Júlia", "Janaína", "Karla", "Kléber", "Lucas", "Lorena", "Lorraine", "Larissa", "Ladislau", "Marcos", "Meire", "Marcelo", "Marcela", "Margarida", "Mércia", "Márcia", "Marli", "Morgana", "Maria", "Norberto", "Natália", "Nataniel", "Núbia", "Ofélia", "Paulo", "Paula", "Pablo", "Pedro", "Raul", "Rafael", "Rafaela", "Ricardo", "Roberto", "Roberta", "Sílvia", "Sílvia", "Silas", "Suélen", "Sara", "Salvador", "Sirineu", "Talita", "Tertuliano", "Vicente", "Víctor", "Vitória", "Yango", "Yago", "Yuri", "Washington", "Warley"];

//colocar os itens do array em um ordem aleatoria.
var suffle = function (nome1, nome2) {
  return Math.random() * 10;
}

var compare = function (nome1, nome2) {
  if ( nome1 < nome2 )
    return -1;
  if ( nome1 > nome2 )
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
var orderAsc = function(nome1, nome2) {  
  return compare(nome1, nome2) * 1;
}
var orderDesc = function(nome1, nome2) {  
  return compare(nome1, nome2) * -1;
}

nomes.sort(suffle);
console.log(nomes);

nomes.sort(orderAsc);
console.log(nomes);

nomes.sort(suffle);
console.log(nomes);

nomes.sort(orderDesc);
console.log(nomes);
```

note que no caso acima, o nome Ígor não foi ordenado da maneira esperada, o mesmo aparece no final do array (orderAsc) ou no inicio (orderDesc);

Para resolver este problema, você pode utilizar o Intl.Collator, ele já vai retornar um inteiro como resultado da comparação, e possui algumas opções adicionais que podem lhe auxiliar com a comparação de strings.

```js
var nomes = ["Alessandro", "Alessandra", "Alexandre", "Aline", "Antônio", "Breno", "Bruna", "Carlos", "Carla", "Célia", "Cecília", "César", "Danilo", "Dalila", "Deneval", "Eduardo", "Eduarda", "Esther", "Elísio", "Fábio", "Fabrício", "Fabrícia", "Félix", "Felícia", "Feliciano", "Frederico", "Fabiano", "Gustavo", "Guilherme", "Gúbio", "Heitor", "Hélio", "Hugo", "Isabel", "Isabela", "Ígor", "João", "Joana", "Júlio César", "Júlio", "Júlia", "Janaína", "Karla", "Kléber", "Lucas", "Lorena", "Lorraine", "Larissa", "Ladislau", "Marcos", "Meire", "Marcelo", "Marcela", "Margarida", "Mércia", "Márcia", "Marli", "Morgana", "Maria", "Norberto", "Natália", "Nataniel", "Núbia", "Ofélia", "Paulo", "Paula", "Pablo", "Pedro", "Raul", "Rafael", "Rafaela", "Ricardo", "Roberto", "Roberta", "Sílvia", "Sílvia", "Silas", "Suélen", "Sara", "Salvador", "Sirineu", "Talita", "Tertuliano", "Vicente", "Víctor", "Vitória", "Yango", "Yago", "Yuri", "Washington", "Warley"];

//colocar os itens do array em um ordem aleatoria.
var suffle = function (nome1, nome2) {
  return Math.random() * 10;
}

var collator = new Intl.Collator("pt-BR", { sensitivity : "base" });
var orderAsc = function(nome1, nome2) {  
  return collator.compare(nome1, nome2) * 1;
}
var orderDesc = function(nome1, nome2) {  
  return collator.compare(nome1, nome2) * -1;
}

nomes.sort(suffle);
console.log(nomes);

nomes.sort(orderAsc);
console.log(nomes);

nomes.sort(suffle);
console.log(nomes);

nomes.sort(orderDesc);
console.log(nomes);
```

note que usei a opção `sensitivity : "base"`, neste caso a comparação sera `case-insensitive` e `accent-sensitive`, então não há a necessidade de fazer um `.toUpperCase()`, e a ordenação vai apresentar o resultado esperado mesmo que as palavras possuam acentos.

porém como o safari ainda não dá suporte ao `Intl.Collator` (E você ainda fala mal do IE ;D), então talvez seja necessario usar um Polyfill: [Intl.js](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/)

Comment: Está acontecendo algo interessante, meu vetor está em ordem decrescente, como alterar isto, quero que comesse no A, B, C .. Z

Comment: @RenanRodrigues, fiz algumas alterações na resposta.